# Type mismatch on a multi criteria Index/Match with Offset in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropValues()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Holdings")
    Dim str2 As String: str2 = "Holdings - FTH & GAAP_crosstab-" & cws.Range("I2").Value & ".xlsx"
    Dim tb As Workbook: Set tb = Application.Workbooks(str2)
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = tb.Worksheets("Holdings - FTH & GAAP_crosstab")
    
    Dim Lim As Long: Lim = cws.Range("A3").Value
    Dim PortAd As String: PortAd = "B6:B" & (Lim + 2)
    Dim CusipAd As String: CusipAd = "A6:A" & (Lim + 2)
    Dim BV, MV, BY, ED, EC, OAS As String
    BV = "V4:V" & Lim
    MV = "Y4:Y" & Lim
    BY = "Z4:Z" & Lim
    ED = "AC4:AC" & Lim
    EC = "AD4:AD" & Lim
    OAS = "AE4:AE" & Lim  
  
    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To cws.Range("B3").Value
            cws.Range("J5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(BV), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
            cws.Range("K5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(MV), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
            cws.Range("L5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(BY), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
            cws.Range("M5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(ED), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
            cws.Range("N5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(EC), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
            cws.Range("O5").Offset(i, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(tws.Range(OAS), WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
                        (cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0)) * (cws.Range(PortAd) = cws.Range("E5").Offset(i, 0)), 0))
        Next i

    End Sub
```

When I try to run it it stops at the first index/match in the loop saying there is a type mismatch. Is there a problem with the Offset function or the Index/Match function? I'm trying to find help on google but I'm having trouble with that.

Cells A3 and B3 have numbers in them (both are results of count functions).
Cell I2 contains 12312019 which is a result of a text function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use array comparison like `(cws.Range(CusipAd) = cws.Range("F5").Offset(i, 0))`  in VBA. One option is to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` with your original formula in string format: `=INDEX(...,MATCH(1,....")`.

Comment: @BigBen oh gotcha! Is that a universal rule for VBA? I am mainly making this macro to save time with calculations as the actual worksheet Index/Match functions take about 6 minutes to calculate.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to load all the data into `Variant` arrays and loop in memory, instead of using `Index`/`Match` or `Evaluate`.

Comment: @BigBen that's a good point! I'll try it.